# Help with tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, displaystyle

So Im having a little problem with a tikzcd-figure in my Thesis. It looks very 'squeezed' - if you understand. Can anyone help? I can simply not get it to look right [image]

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=small]
& Finanspolitisk\,disciplin \arrow[dash]{dr}{[Den\,liberale\,model]} \\
Indkomstlighed  \arrow[dash]{ur}{[Den\,konservative\,model]}
\arrow[dash]{rr}{[Den\,skandinaviske\,model]} &&
Besk\text{æ}ftigelsesv\text{æ}kst
\end{tikzcd}
\]}
```

Answer (score 6):

You want textual cells and labels, so you can first set `math mode=false`; you can also set all arrows to dashes and make the labels smaller.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  math mode=false,
  labels={font=\scriptsize},
  row sep=huge,
  column sep=small,
  arrows=dash,
]
& Finanspolitisk disciplin \arrow[dr,"{[Den liberale model]}"]
\\
Indkomstlighed
  \arrow[ur,"{[Den konservative model]}"]
  \arrow[rr,"{[Den skandinaviske model]}"]
&&
Beskæftigelsesvækst
\end{tikzcd}
 \]

\end{document}
```

The braces are necessary in order not to confuse the parser.

[image]

You can make it “symmetric”, with a bit more work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  math mode=false,
  labels={font=\scriptsize},
  row sep=huge,
  column sep={0em,between borders},
  arrows=dash,
]
& Finanspolitisk disciplin \arrow[dr,"{[Den liberale model]}"]
\\
Indkomstlighed
  \arrow[ur,"{[Den konservative model]}"]
  \arrow[rr,"{[Den skandinaviske model]}"]
&&
Beskæftigelsesvækst
\end{tikzcd}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=small]
& \text{Finanspolitisk\,disciplin} \arrow[dash]{dr}{[\text{Den liberale model}]} \\
\text{Indkomstlighed} \arrow[dash]{ur}{[\text{Den konservative model}]} \arrow[dash]{rr}{[\text{Den\,skandinaviske\,model}]} && \text{Beskæftigelsesvækst}
\end{tikzcd}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]